# How many "tiles" for a flexagon with $n$ sides?

Tags: origami

For a flexagon with $n $ sides, how many tiles does it have?

> A tile is when the components are stuck together and not folded, The number of tiles are the number of triangles you can see on one side.

I am looking for a number sequence.
I am assuming there are $6n$ tiles in a flexagon, but since I have only a three sides flexagon, I can not tell for sure. A tile includes one side printed tiles, where there are only two instances.

#### Is this right, or does it require correction?

Before you answer this, if you do not know what a flexagon is, I suggest you research one first.

Comment: Can you provide us with the definition of flexagon you are using? The only place I know them from is that old vihart video.

Comment: So a tile is a pair of triangles that share an edge that could fold but are positioned with the fold open?